# How to get jSon data from a url in html

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to get json data from: https://www.topurbanaradio.com/ps/scast.php

I've tried to use several codes that work for others and I can't get any information from the url.

The last code I tried was this one:

```js
$(function() {
  var entries = [];
  var JSONurl = "https://www.topurbanaradio.com/ps/scast.php";
  $.getJSON(JSONurl, function(data) {
    $.each(data.entries, function(i, f) {
      var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.cancion + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.artista + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.almbumart + "</td>" + "</tr>"
      $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="profile">
      <table id="entrydata" border="1">
        <thead>
          <th>Artista</th>
          <th>Cancion</th>
          <th>AlbumArt</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: What are you trying to get? Are you sure there's JSON data there?

Comment: I'm getting CORS errors when I try to fetch data from that URL. You are likely also getting those error. Look at the console of your browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Add **tr** inside **tbody** the for your table and do a `$each` for object.value you receiving from the `api`.
then append the result to **tr** i recommend also a loader the time the result show up.

Open that with **CORS extension**

**NOTE** : i am using firefox + [CORS](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/)

```js
$(function() {
  var entries = [];
  var JSONurl = "https://www.topurbanaradio.com/ps/scast.php";
  $.getJSON(JSONurl, function(data) {
    $.each(Object.values(data), function(i, value) {
      console.log(value)
      var tblRow = "<td>" + value + "</td>"
      $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody tr");
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="profile">
      <table id="entrydata" border="1">
        <thead>
          <th>Artista</th>
          <th>Cancion</th>
          <th>AlbumArt</th>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue with **CORS**

because when I tried to run it from localhost or direct from HTML file, I got CORS error.

if you have access to this endpoint you need to allow CORS for your domain OR install CORS extension in your browser just for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**Put simply, there are many problems here and this will not work in production.**

First, cross domain AJAX requests aren’t allowed by browsers.

Second, the server isn’t returning the right headers.

Running `curl -L -IX GET https://www.topurbanaradio.com/ps/scast.php` returns the following headers which includes a content type of `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` (HTML) vs `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8` (JSON).

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Sep 2019 19:35:39 GMT
Server: Apache
Upgrade: h2
Connection: Upgrade
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Is this code running on `www.topurbanaradio.com`? If not, you will hit [cross-domain (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) errors as the server behind `www.topurbanaradio.com` is not sending the right `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` headers.

If they intended on serving cross-domain requests, they would send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $.getJSON("https://www.topurbanaradio.com/ps/scast.php", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Check the console.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at https://www.topurbanaradio.com/ps/scast.php.
>   (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a XHR to another domain unless that document explicitly contains the CORS headers allowing it (this is to block scripts from stealing sensitive data).

To get data from an external document that does not have CORS headers, there is [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), which can be included as a a `<script>` tag in your page. This requires that the other site can be updated to support this. This can be dangerous, as it allows the other site to insert a script to do *anything* on your page - only do this if you trust the other site.